Selenium not bypassing cloudfare on linux
I am writing a discord bot that web scrapes dexscreener.com with some filter periodically and outputs the tokens in a discord channel. When I run the code on my windows machine it works fine but when i try to run it through a linux web server it does not bypass the cloudfare captcha. I looked for a solution online and i think the problem is that the linux server ip is static. I don't know how to solve that captcha. Here is the Screenshot for the page.
Here is my selenium code:
def initialize_selenium():
    global selenium_driver
    selenium_driver = Driver(
        browser="chrome",
        uc=True,
        headless2=True,
        incognito=False,
        agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.5615.138 Safari/537.36 AVG/112.0.21002.139",
        do_not_track=True,
        undetectable=True,
    )
    stealth(selenium_driver,
        languages=["en-US", "en"],
        vendor="Google Inc.",
        platform="Win32",
        webgl_vendor="Intel Inc.",
        renderer="Intel Iris OpenGL Engine",
        fix_hairline=True,
        )
    selenium_driver.get(DEXSCREENER_URL)

def handle_cloudflare_challenge(driver):
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(
            (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe[title='Widget containing a Cloudflare security challenge']")
        ))
        
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
            (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "label.ctp-checkbox-label")
        )).click()
        
        driver.switch_to.default_content()
        
        WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@href]"))
        )
        
        print("Cloudflare challenge solved successfully")
    except (TimeoutException, NoSuchElementException) as e:
        print(f"Failed to solve Cloudflare challenge: {e}")

def selenium_task():
    global selenium_driver
    if not selenium_driver:
        initialize_selenium()
    
    selenium_driver.refresh()
    
    try:
        WebDriverWait(selenium_driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
            (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe[title='Widget containing a Cloudflare security challenge']")
        ))
        print("Cloudflare challenge detected. Attempting to solve...")
        handle_cloudflare_challenge(selenium_driver)
    except TimeoutException:
        selenium_driver.save_screenshot('lol.png')
        print("No Cloudflare challenge detected. Proceeding with normal operation.")
    
    try:
        WebDriverWait(selenium_driver, 20).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@href]"))
        )
    except TimeoutException:
        print("Timeout waiting for page to load. Returning empty list.")
        return []
    
    hrefs = extract_hrefs(selenium_driver)
    tokens = filter_urls_by_token_pattern(hrefs)
    return tokens

I tried using Selenium Stealth and Selenium Base, but made no progress

This class of problem isn't well suited to Stack Overflow: We try to build answers that will remain useful indefinitely, but this is a cat-and-mouse game: as soon as tricks for bypassing a captcha are public, that incentivizes the people in charge of that tool to update it to break that bypass. The bypasses that are going to work and keep working are ones you build privately and never publish, release, publicize, or overuse (and which nobody independently rediscovers and publishes/releases/overuses/etc).
